# HTML Email image dissapears in yahoo mail

Tags: html, css, image, html-email

I have created a newsletter containing two identical logos, because the logo's position in the newsletter will differ from desktop to mobile.

The only problem I have encountered, is that yahoo mail will show none of them, no matter what I do.

The [newsletter can be seen here](http://thomasteilmann.com/nyhedsbrev) and the relevant markup is:

```
<a href="http://ezzence.dk">
    <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="logo" width="150"/>
</a>
```

SOLUTION:

The problem was yahoo mail using my media queries, because yahoo dont know the syntax. I used this workaround 
http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/stop_yahoo_mail_from_rendering_your_media_queries

Comment: I take it you change the src to an absolute path in the e-mail? Otherwise that might be your problem.

Comment: You should include code in your question so that it's complete and self-contained, and doesn't rely on another site for important information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was yahoo mail using my media queries, cause yahoo dont know the syntax of media queries. I used this workaround to fix it. Its a little dirt, but the only thing that did the trick.

http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/stop_yahoo_mail_from_rendering_your_media_queries

Answer (score 3):

Upload image on some server and then link it to your code this wont work

```
<img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="logo" width="150"/>
```

Try with this

```
<img src="http://someurl.com/img/logo.jpg" alt="logo" width="150"/>
```

Comment: But isnt it funny that its only Yahoo thats causing me trouble? I'll try it out though :)

Comment: unfortunately this didnt fix my problem. I think it might have something to do with the display css property. Not quite sure why the logo dissapears though

Comment: My problem was that yahoo mail was interpreting/using my media queries, because yahoo mail simply dont understand the syntax. I used this workaround http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/stop_yahoo_mail_from_rendering_your_media_queries

Upvote though, for correct practice of image linking.

Comment: Oh, didnt noticed that you are using media queries.. thanks for the link tough.. its will help me in future.

Answer (score 2):

Use [**absolute URLs**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676525%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) otherwise your email client won't know to which domain to redirect.